# What is electionId on Mongoose update?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

After model update using Mongoose, the following data is returned:

```
{ 
  ok: 1,
  nModified: 1,
  n: 1,
  lastOp: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1463881720 },
  electionId: 573e2656b8b7cd4def436dd8
}
```

What is the **electionId** field? I find in [Mongoose Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) and no found anything.

Comment: Are you connected to a replica set?

Comment: @user3100115, no. Just a one update with upsert true.

Comment: maybe this https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server_write_commands.rst?#situational-fields 
can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @4832190 for the comment, according to [Write Commands Specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server_write_commands.rst?#situational-fields) (Situational Fields):

`electionId`: MONGODB ONLY. Optional ObjectId field representing the last primary election Id.